# Remove space between keyboard and composer in React-Native-Gifted-Chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm using the react-native-gifted-chat package for my React Native application.
Somehow there is a space between the composer and the keyboard, although I did not customise the GiftedChat.

Marked orange in the attached screenshot:

[image]

I already tried to customise the composer or any other component, with not effect.

Answer (score 1):

i'm also facing same problem after some time i find this solution and it's work for me.

```
     <GiftedChat
                    isAnimated
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    scrollToBottom={true}
                    renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
                    onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
                    inverted={false}
                    isLoadingEarlier={true}
                    messagesContainerStyle={{ color: 'gray' }}
                    bottomOffset={0} // add this line and space is remove
                    renderBubble={props => {
                        return (
                            <Bubble
                                {...props}

                                textStyle={{
                                    right: {
                                        color: 'white',
                                    },
                                    left: {
                                        color: '#24204F',
                                    },
                                }}
                                wrapperStyle={{
                                    left: {
                                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                                    },
                                    right: {
                                        backgroundColor: "#ff3b00", // red
                                    },
                                }}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                    renderInputToolbar={props => {
                        return (<InputToolbar {...props} containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#e2e2e2' }} />);
                    }}
                    user={{
                        _id: 1
                    }}
                />
```

hope this willl work for you
bottomOffset={0} // add this line and space is remove

Comment: @MarioMurrent  i'm testing in ios but in android you must to follow installations steps and it will be works.

Comment: Okay, Ill try it again - for now it does not work, the message window is outside of the visible area

Comment: @MarioMurrent did you try bottomOffset={0} in your code because it's working for me in ios.

Answer (score 0):

install  react-native-iphone-x-helper

and add these lines according to your code.

```
import { getBottomSpace } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';



<GiftedChat 
    bottomOffset={getBottomSpace()}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: This will remove the space? Does this also work for Expo Apps?

Comment: Yes, I also use this in my app. but i don't know how this will act on expo apps.

Comment: Does not really work :(

Answer (score 0):

As found on the docs itself, simply get the insets:

```
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
<GiftedChat
   bottomOffset={insets.bottom}
   ...
 />
```

This will fix your issue dynamically.

Comment: Not really. This does not help, its only working for iOS